# Making sense of forall and exists output on empty list

Tags: scala

```
scala> val l = List()
l: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> l.forall(x=>false)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> l.forall(x=>true)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> l.exists(x=>false)
res2: Boolean = false

scala> l.exists(x=>true)
res3: Boolean = false
```

For above 2 predicate, now that no element exists in the list, how come forall return true? I am confused. could you somebody help explain?

Comment: The case of forall being true on an empty list is called 'vacuously true'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could rephrase that `forall` means that none of the elements of the list violate the given predicate. In case there *are* *no* elements, none of them violates it.

The source code of [`forall`](https://www.assembla.com/code/scala-eclipse-toolchain/git/nodes/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala?rev=f037b9d76693bac370db31e50b2565d0fcd97ec6) explicitly returns true if a collection is empty:

```
def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
       ...
    }
    true
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The semantics of these methods was chosen to be coherent with the semantics of the universal and the existential quantifier in formal logic.

Method `forall` acts as the universal quantifier - it returns `true` if there is no element in the collection for which the predicate is `false`. If there are no elements, then the predicate is never false and `forall` is true.

Method `exists` acts as the existential quantifier. It returns `true` if there is at least one element for which the predicate is `true`. If there are no elements, then the predicate is never true and `exists` returns false.

Answer (score 4):

Unit of conjunction(i.e. `and`) is `true` whereas unit of disjunction (i.e. `or`) is `false`

Consider a list `lst` of with `n` elements.

`lst.forall(f)` is equivalent to

```
true && f(lst(0)) && ... && f(lst(n-1))
```

`lst.exists(f)` is equivalent to

```
false || f(lst(0)) || ... || f(lst(n-1))
```

In case of an empty list, only first term in above expressions is there.